# Power bi fit width of chart without scroll

Tags: charts, powerbi

I'm having an issue when I'm trying to get a chart between 2 dates printable from Power BI. I need the chart to fit in the width in the window without the scroll.
Anyone knows how to fix it?

[image]
Thanks!

BR,
Blen

Comment: Just use date no time, in case need time then create separate time dimeasion and use hierarchy to show date first and then time in drill down.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not solved the problem. I still need the times in chart but only when hovering over the dots. But still theres a fixed width between the timepoints. Is there any way to solve this problem? For now I can only print 1,5 day of statistics on paper.

Comment: There is no zoom feature where you can set the visual screen for print, but you may try add separate visual as tooltip for a day, which shows detail breakdown for the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, the problem was that the date column wasn't really formatted as date, after I change the Data type to "Date/Time" the chart suddenly fitted to width automatically.

Comment: Thanks alot. Sometimes you get blind :)